# Unity - best way to make intro with images

Tags: unity, c#

I have made and rendered an intro in blender for my unity game. The intro currently consists of 150 PNG-images. Should I make it into a video before importing it to unity or should I just import the images to unity and handle the animation there and if so how do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an animated video, then encode it as a video in [one of the formats Unity supports](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VideoSources-FileCompatibility.html), import it into Unity as a [video clip](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-VideoClip.html) and play it with the [video player component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-VideoPlayer.html). If you want to just play back the video in full screen mode, then I would recommend to use the render mode "Camera Near Plane" and assign your main camera as the target camera.

This will require fewer resources to play back, require a smaller filesize and will likely be far easier to accomplish.

Using multiple PNG images would only be a good idea if you want to show a slideshow of static images which each stay on the screen for multiple frames. Like [this hand-drawn intro sequence from Witcher III](https://youtu.be/dd2gz6AxYoA?t=23). If I would create an intro like that, then I would use a [timeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.2/manual/index.html) to control which image stays on screen for how long and how their positions and scales are animated.